# Use the az installer on a VM - through azure powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am attempting to install an artifact through an azure VM - I have remoted into the VM through the powershell on azure and am running the following command:

`Enter-AzVm -Name <MyVM> -ResourceGroupName <MyResourceGroup> -Credential (get-credential)`

When I'm connected onto the VM I'm attempting this download command which works on my local machine:

`az artifacts universal download --organization <MyOrganization> --project=<MyProject> --scope project --feed <MyFeed> --name <MyFirstPackage> --version 0.0.1 --path .`

This is the error I'm getting while attempting that download :

**The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program**

I tried to run the command to install CLI on the VM which runs, but after that installation run I cannot see *az --version* with the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `Enter-AzVm` to remote into the VM to install Azure CLI, seems the `Enter-AzVm` just works in Azure Cloud Shell(not sure).

I installed the Azure CLI successfully via `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` command in a **Windows** VM, when I test `az --version` in cloud shell after remoting into the VM with `Enter-AzVm`, it works fine, you could follow the steps below.

1.Save the command below in local as a `installcli.ps1` file.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'; rm .\AzureCLI.msi
```

2.Run the command below in local.

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'groupname' -VMName 'vmname' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\installcli.ps1'
```

[image]

3.After the command completed, navigate to the cloud shell, use `Enter-AzVm` to remote into the VM, then run `az --version`, it works fine.

[image]

---

**Actually**, if the steps above not work for you, you can also store the azure cli command as a `.ps1` file like `step 1`, then use `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` to run it, it will work.

Comment: I followed this step by step - and got this when running a az --version : PS C:\Users\demouser\Documents> az --version
The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (az:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @DEnumber50 Not sure what caused it, it works fine on my side.